# How to improve performance of Insert INTO (...) select query?

Tags: mysql

right now I am trying to write a query that reduces the data in my database. My plan is to get the average values from one minute.

```
INSERT INTO reduced (current, total, time_stamp)
SELECT
    AVG(current) AS average,
    MAX(total) as total,
    MAX(time_stamp)
FROM
(
    SELECT * from data2  WHERE id <= '500' AND id >= '6'
) AS test
WHERE
    time_stamp <= '2019-05-03 21:24:30' AND
    time_stamp >= '2019-05-03 21:23:30'
```

If I only execute the Select statement it is done within 0,002 seconds. But as soon as I add the INSERT part it needs several seconds. (3-5 seconds)
The problem here is, that I want to repeat that query for the whole data set(always add one minute), so that it would take too much time to calculate. 
So I am wondering if there is a way to speed up this insert process.
Normally the insert statement works very fast too. 
So I think the problem occurs when linking insert and select in one query.

Comment: The subquery isn't ideal, and maybe we could improve upon that, but the first thing that stands out here is that you are only inserting a _single_ record.  Did you intend to use `GROUP BY` in your select query?

Comment: Hello @Tim , thanks for your answer. I did not knew, that you can use group by for time intervals. My query now looks like this: INSERT INTO reduced (current, total, time_stamp) SELECT
    AVG(current) AS average,
    MAX(total) as total,
    MAX(time_stamp)
FROM data2

GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 60 and is working fine. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @lucas Can you post your own solution as an answer?

Comment: *"The subquery isn't ideal, and maybe we could improve upon that,"* @TimBiegeleisen pretty sure (atleast the modern 5.7+) MySQL optimizers are smart enough to see that the delivered table is a "non changing" resultset (not sure how to call it) .. And that it can push up the WHERE from the inner SQL to the outer SQL and it can remove the inner SELECT completly.. -> [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/txMvvYSqoReLCQQEwyHCUd/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen I figured out the following solution:

```
INSERT INTO reduced (current, total, time_stamp) 
SELECT AVG(current) AS average
     , MAX(total) as total
     , MAX(time_stamp) 
  FROM data2 
 GROUP 
    BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 60
```

The idea here is to use group by to create the time intervals, so that I do not have to iterate over the dataset with a loop and only have to use the insert once.

Comment: It's a bit odd to store a bunch of time-period-specific aggregate data with no way of relating it to its time period.

Comment: Yeah I admit it is not the best solution. But for my use case it is good enough, because I only use these data for visualization. The user does not have to see data from every second. So with this query I can reduce the amount of data I have to send to the client

Comment: ? But it's unordered data  !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean by unordered?

Comment: Rows in relational databases represent unordered sets.